# pthread_cond_timedwait returning immediately

Tags: c, multithreading, conditional-statements, system, pthreads

I'm having a strange problem. I have the following code:

```
    dbg("condwait: timeout = %d, %d\n", 
        abs_timeout->tv_sec, abs_timeout->tv_nsec);
    ret = pthread_cond_timedwait( &q->q_cond, &q->q_mtx, abs_timeout );
    if (ret == ETIMEDOUT)
    {
      dbg("cond timed out\n");
      return -ETIMEDOUT;
    }
```

`dbg` calls `gettimeofday` before every line and prepends the line with the time. It results in the following output:

```
    7.991151: condwait: timeout = 5, 705032704
    7.991158: cond timed out
```

As you can see, only 7 microseconds passed in between the two debug lines, yet `pthread_cond_timedwait` returned `ETIMEDOUT`. How can this happen? I even tried setting the clock to something else when initializing the cond variable:

```
int ret;
ret = pthread_condattr_init(&attributes);
if (ret != 0) printf("CONDATTR INIT FAILED: %d\n", ret);
ret = pthread_condattr_setclock(&attributes, CLOCK_REALTIME);
if (ret != 0) printf("SETCLOCK FAILED: %d\n", ret);
ret = pthread_cond_init( &q->q_cond, &attributes );
if (ret != 0) printf("COND INIT FAILED: %d\n", ret);
```

(none of the error messages are printed out). I tried both `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

This code is part of a blocking queue. I need functionality such that if nothing gets put on this queue in 5 seconds, something else happens. The mutex and the cond are both initialized, as the blocking queue works fine if I don't use `pthread_cond_timedwait`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

pthread_cond_timedwait takes an absolute time, not a relative time. You need to make your wait time absolute by adding to the current time to your timeout value.

Comment: Oh got it. You can use pthread_get_expiration_np() to figure out what the abs time is.

Comment: @Claudiu pthread_get_expiration_np() is not available on my GNU/Linux. Instead I had to: `timeval now; 
gettimeofday(&now, NULL); long int abstime_ns_large = now.tv_usec*1000 + delay_ns; timespec abstime = { now.tv_sec + (abstime_ns_large / 1000000000), abstime_ns_large % 1000000000 };` where delay_ns is the desired delay in nanoseconds. Then use abstime in your pthread_cond_timedwait call.

Answer (score 8):

Overflow in `timespec` is usually the culprit for weird timeouts.
Check for **EINVAL:**

```
void timespec_add(struct timespec* a, struct timespec* b, struct timespec* out)
{
    time_t sec = a->tv_sec + b->tv_sec;
    long nsec = a->tv_nsec + b->tv_nsec;

    sec += nsec / 1000000000L;
    nsec = nsec % 1000000000L;

    out->tv_sec = sec;
    out->tv_nsec = nsec;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The condition variable can spuriously unblock. You need to check it in a loop and check the condition each time through. You'll probably need to update the timeout value too.

I found some documentation for `pthread_cond_timedwait` [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html).

> When using condition variables there
>   is always a Boolean predicate
>   involving shared variables associated
>   with each condition wait that is true
>   if the thread should proceed. Spurious
>   wakeups from the
>   pthread_cond_timedwait() or
>   pthread_cond_wait() functions may
>   occur. Since the return from
>   pthread_cond_timedwait() or
>   pthread_cond_wait() does not imply
>   anything about the value of this
>   predicate, the predicate should be
>   re-evaluated upon such return.

Answer (score 1):

As already in other answers mentioned you have to use the absolute time. Since C11 you can use `timespec_get()`.

```
struct timespec time;
timespec_get(&time, TIME_UTC);
time.tv_sec += 5;

pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &time);
```