# pthread_cond_timedwait on Windows returns ETIMEDOUT too early

Tags: windows, time, pthreads

Under pthreads-win32 2.7 and 2.8, pthread_cond_timedwait will sometimes return too early with ETIMEDOUT.  There is only one waiting thread and only one signaling thread. I do not believe this is a case of the condition variable spuriously unblocking as in the question: [pthread_cond_timedwait returning immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660916/pthread-cond-timedwait-returning-immediately)

Internally the Win32 pthread implementation calls _ftime() to determine the current time, and compares it with an absolute time in the future to wait. The accuracy of this timer is insufficient (I think) and so the relative time to wait is often computed incorrectly.  Say I request a wait of a second in the future:

```
struct timespec ts;
ts.tv_sec = static_cast<long>(time(NULL) + sec_rel);
ts.tv_nsec = 0;
```

// OR

```
struct timespec ts;
struct _timeb currSysTime;
_ftime(&currSysTime);
ts.tv_sec = static_cast<long>(currSysTime.time + sec_rel);
ts.tv_nsec = currSysTime.millitm * 1000000;

if( pthread_cond_timedwait(&m_cond, &m_Mutex, &ts) ) // returns too early
```

Both of these approaches to determine the current time don't mix well with the pthread code that computes the number of milliseconds to wait given an absolute time, in ptw32_relmillisecs.c (see end of this post)  **ptw32_relmillisecs will often return a small number of milliseconds rather than the nearly 1000 that are expected.**

What I'm doing right now is looping with my own timer until the timeout has truly elapsed, but I feel that I must be computing the future absolute time incorrectly.

---

```
    INLINE DWORD
ptw32_relmillisecs (const struct timespec * abstime)
{
  const int64_t NANOSEC_PER_MILLISEC = 1000000;
  const int64_t MILLISEC_PER_SEC = 1000;
  DWORD milliseconds;
  int64_t tmpAbsMilliseconds;
  int64_t tmpCurrMilliseconds;

 struct _timeb currSysTime;



  /* 
   * Calculate timeout as milliseconds from current system time. 
   */

  /*
   * subtract current system time from abstime in a way that checks
   * that abstime is never in the past, or is never equivalent to the
   * defined INFINITE value (0xFFFFFFFF).
   *
   * Assume all integers are unsigned, i.e. cannot test if less than 0.
   */
  tmpAbsMilliseconds =  (int64_t)abstime->tv_sec * MILLISEC_PER_SEC;
  tmpAbsMilliseconds += ((int64_t)abstime->tv_nsec + (NANOSEC_PER_MILLISEC/2)) / NANOSEC_PER_MILLISEC;

  /* get current system time */
  _ftime(&currSysTime);

  tmpCurrMilliseconds = (int64_t) currSysTime.time * MILLISEC_PER_SEC;
  tmpCurrMilliseconds += (int64_t) currSysTime.millitm;

  if (tmpAbsMilliseconds > tmpCurrMilliseconds)
    {
      milliseconds = (DWORD) (tmpAbsMilliseconds - tmpCurrMilliseconds);
      if (milliseconds == INFINITE)
        {
          /* Timeouts must be finite */
          milliseconds--;
        }
    }
  else
    {
      /* The abstime given is in the past */
      milliseconds = 0;
    }

  return milliseconds;
}
```

Comment: As near as I can tell you can't use time(NULL) but must instead fill out the tv_nsec field by using _ftime() or a related function.  Even given that fix, you still cannot use sub-second timeouts with pthreads on Windows due to _ftime()'s poor precision.

Comment: The code you have pasted doesn't match what is in 2.7.0 or 2.8.0.  That code has #ifdef's. Whether or not it calls `_ftime` or does its own conversion from Windows time to the Unix Epoch time, depends on the preprocessor symbol `NEEDS_FTIME`. What if it's doing its own calculation and it doesn't exactly match what `_ftime` puts out (what you're using?)

Comment: I removed the sections not present in the final translation unit.  NEED_FTIME is only defined on WinCE (see config.h:/* Define if you don't have Win32 ftime. (eg. WinCE)  */
#undef NEED_FTIME

Comment: I see. When you say "ptw32_relmillisecs will often return a small number of milliseconds rather than the nearly 1000 that are expected", how small is small?

Comment: I think there are two separate problems. One was only using time(NULL) (which NEVER took into account milliseconds). That's been rectified by using _ftime everywhere so the error is the same: integer second timeouts seem to work just fine.  What's still failing with incorrect millisecond computation is the say a 500ms wait.  I've abandoned sub-second waits for now until I can figure this out.  Thankfully this codebase only waits for whole seconds anyway.